# Advice on PHP Data Table fetched from MySQL

Tags: php, css, mysql, pdo

I've written some PHP and CSS to query a MySQL database table that I have running on a WAMP server.  I have two files that run, index.php and test.php.  Index contains a selector box which allows the user to choose a filter option from 'family.'  Ultimately I would like for the selected option to be implemented into the SELECT query that determines the data output in the PHP portion of test.php.

For instance, if the user selects "capacitor" from index.php, I need the table that is created to display only the family entries that match "capacitor" (as well as all of the corresponding details like "capacitance", "voltage", and "price").  Currently, my PHP just fetches the entire table (Ex. picture below).

[image]

I know that I am needing to use the $_POST super global to fetch the user input and place it into the SELECT query, but I am not sure how.

**EDIT: When I attempt to narrow the returned data by using a WHERE modifier, I receive the following error**

ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'capacitor' in 'where clause'

Below is index.php

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
   <select name="family">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Any family</option>
      <option value="capacitor">capacitor</option>
      <option value="resistor">resistor</option>
      <option value="ferrite bead">ferrite bead</option>
   </select>
   <input name="search" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>

</html>
```

Below is test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>test.php</title>
      <style>
         table {
         border-collapse: collapse;

         width: 50%;
         }
         th, td {
         text-align: left;
         padding: 8px;
         }
         th {
         background-color: SkyBlue;
         }
      tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
      tr:hover {background-color: AliceBlue;} 
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>    
      <p>
      <?php

      try {
         $con= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysql', "root", "kelly188");
         $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         $query = "SELECT * FROM testv2";

         //first query just gets the column names
         print "<table>";
         $result = $con->query($query);

         //return only the first row (we only need field names)
         $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         print " <tr>";
         foreach ($row as $field => $value){
            print " <th>$field</th>";
            }
         // end loop
         print " </tr>";

         //second query gets the data
         $data = $con->query(**PERTAINS TO EDIT**);
         $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         foreach($data as $row){
            print " <tr>";
               foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
              print " <td>$value</td>";
               } //end row loop
            print " </tr>";
            } //end record loop
         print "</table>";
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
         echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
      } // end try
      ?>
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why execute the same query twice? You should use a `where` clause to limit the returned data.

Comment: See my edit.  Something about my second query is not right, just not sure what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture the family requested:

```
$filter_key = "";
if(isset($_POST['family'])){
    $filter_key = $_POST['family'];
}
```

them yu have to conform your query using the filter setted:

```
if(!empty($filter_key))
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE family = "'.$filter_key.'"';
else
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM testv2';
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create the second query as a select for the records where the family is the value you loop over, something like this:

```
$data= $con->query('SELECT * from testv2 where family = $field');
```

Comment: You need to use double quotes if you are using this syntax, eg. `$data= $con->query("SELECT * from testv2 where family = $field");`. Also query is spelled incorrectly.